# How to update status on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I want to update status on facebook by app ,so i have searched a lot but not able to update status on facebook   ,i have imported facebook sdk3.15.0,it gives permission error in logcat.so let me know how is it possible to update status ,and it gives response null ,my code is

```
  imgfacebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                    loginToFacebook();
                }
            });


    public void loginToFacebook() {
            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

            if (access_token != null) {
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                postToWall(CheckRating);
            }

            if (expires != 0) {
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }

            if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                facebook.authorize(this,
                        new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                        new DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                // Function to handle cancel event
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                // Function to handle complete event
                                // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                editor.putString("access_token",
                                        facebook.getAccessToken());
                                editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                        facebook.getAccessExpires());
                                editor.commit();
                                postToWall(CheckRating);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError error) {
                                // Function to handle error

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                                // Function to handle Facebook errors

                            }

                        });

public void postToWall(final String msg) {

        try {
            // Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            // parameters.putString("message", "Text is lame. Listen up:");
            // parameters.putString("name", "Name");
            // parameters.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
            // parameters.putString("caption", "Caption");
            // parameters.putString("description", "Description");
            //
            // String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,
            // "POST");
            // Log.v("response", response);
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", "Text is lame. Listen up:");
            parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
            String response = facebook.request(parameters);
            Log.v("response", response);
            System.out.println("Response is ....." + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Response is nulll......");
        }
        // post on user's wall.

    }
```

Comment: did u got your `app_id` from fb developer page?

Comment: yes @prabhakaran i am using app_id from facebook

Comment: @user3098271 then what error your getting..

Comment: @user3098271 what is line no 101

Comment: logcat gives Should not pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish or manage authorization,but i have given permissions

Comment: you should check did you add `internet` permission and check your `hashcode`